# Having trouble with explode() in uploadify.php

Tags: php, uploadify, explode

I have this snippet from my uploadify.php:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

$path = pathinfo($targetFile);

// this portion here will be true if and only if the file name of the uploaded file does not contain '.', except of course the dot(.) before the file extension
$count = 1;
list( $filename, $ext) = explode( '.', $name, );
$newTargetFile = $targetFolder . $filename . '.' . $ext;
while( file_exists( $newTargetFile)) {
    $newTargetFile = $targetFolder . $filename . '(' . ++$count . ')' . '.' . $ext;
}

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('pdf'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$newTargetFile);
    echo $newTargetFile;
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
return $newTargetFile;
}
```

Basically this is quite working. Uploading the file and getting the path of the file which will then be inserted on the database and so on. But, I tried uploading a file which file name looks like this,

```
filename.1.5.3.pdf
```

and when succesfully uploaded, the file name then became `filename` alone, without having the file extension and not to mention the file name is not complete. From what I understood, the problem lies on my explode(). It exploded the string having the delimiter `'.'` and then assigns it to the variables. What will I do to make the `explode()` cut the string into two where the first half is the filename and the second is the file extension? PLease help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use explode, use a function designed for the job: [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: And for completeness sake, $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

Comment: My bad bro.TSK. It did not occur in me to use pathinfo(). It really worked fine for me. Thanks a lot. :)